# Mongoose: Validation failed; field: utils.clone is not a function

Tags: mongoose, protocol-buffers

I am trying to save a document using mongoose that has been sent to my server via grpc. The mongoose schema and the corresponding protobuf message have been generated from the same JSON schema.

Unfortunately, mongoose fails to validate the document and throws me the following error:

```
Error: MyModel validation failed: myfield: utils.clone is not a function, _id: utils.clone is not a function
at ValidationError.inspect
```

My search online hasn't revealed a whole lot about this problem. Does anyone have a clue as to what could be going on here?

Thanks a lot!